# Block file from accessing using .htaccess for a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, block

I have a website for e.g.

```
www.domain.com
```

And I have another subdomain for e.g.

```
test.domain.com
```

Both my main and subdomain point to same directory which is **public_html**.

I want to block access to

```
test.domain.com/test.jpg
```

but not

```
domain.com/test.jpg
```

Please note that this **test.jpg** is same file for both main and subdomain as they both point to same directory. So how do I block it for subdomain but not for main domain using .htaccess? Or is there any other way of doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If test.domain.com and domain.com in one VirtualHost, easy use .htaccess and mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =test.domain.com
RewriteRule ^test.jpg - [F]

$ curl domain.com/test.jpg
123
$ curl test.domain.com/test.jpg
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
```

Comment: is there a generic way to do this blocking test.* without specifying the full domain name?